# Google recaptcha workflow

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise, grecaptcha

I would like to know does my workflow correctly or not for the google recaptcha

I have added recaptcha enterprise and recaptcha v2 in my login page. Below is my workflow

1. When user come to my login page. System will go to fetch recaptcha score.
2. If score below 0.7 or user input wrong username or password three times. System will show the recaptcha v2 (checkbox). The user need to clear the recaptcha checkbox before he login again
3. Once the recaptcha checkbox showed in the login page. It will hold for 1 day (cookies will handle). Mean, within this 1 day, this user always need to clear the checkbox before login.

Im not sure, is it a good partices for the Google recaptcha?